# Why does CUPS need drivers if the clients already have them?

Tags: cups

I mean, if CUPS is only an intermediary and we need drivers at the clients anyway, why do we have to install them on CUPS? Won't the clients send a printer language job? So, why does CUPS need a driver if the job is already translated to printer language?

Comment: I'm talking about a Samba-CUPS solution to provide a printing server for Windows clients.

Comment: I think this question belongs to UL or SU but not to SF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like CUPS needs no PPD files at all if the client (ex.: Windows user) already used a printer driver to output a job in some format (ex.: PS) accepted by the printer. In this case, CUPS acts only as an intermediary and the printer queue could be defined as a raw queue. Have just tested that cenario and it worked just fine.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Network_2

Answer (score 2):

We should separate drivers from printer description files and from filters.

Applications need drivers (either themselves or provided by the operating system), to transform whatever page format they use into the language understood by the operating system.  As far as I can remember, MS Windows clients usually either generate Postscript directly, or more commonly use GDI, which Windows then transforms into whatever language the printer understands: Adobe Postscript, Adobe PDF, Epson ESC/P or ESC/P2, HP PCL, IBM AFP… Wikipedia has [an extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language).

[Filters](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-filter.html) work as server-side drivers, in that they will accept input in some format generated by the application and transform it into some format accepted by the printer.  They could be needed when the client for some reason cannot generate the format understood by the printer.

As far as I know, Cups needs no drivers or filters, but can use printer descriptions, so that it will know the printers’ capabilities, and pass that information to clients.  PPDs ([Postscript printer description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description) files) are usually available for Postscript printers, and I assume also PDF ones, but I guess they do not exist for MS GDI and other lesser printers such as Epson ESC/P2 or HP PCL ones; so I can see the need perhaps not for drivers, but some equivalent to PPDs would be convenient, which could be provided in the (proprietary) drivers’ packages.

By the way, what would be UL or SU, as alternatives to Server fault, as in Marco’s comment above?

Comment: Thanks, gf_. So I guess the question belongs here, since Cups is a service, not anything inherent to Unix or GNU/Linux, and definetively nothing to do with userspace.

Comment: When I say "drivers" I mean the PPDs. So the question, in another words, would be: Why does CUPS need PPD files if the clients already have the PS driver?

Comment: Just to make it clearer for future, if any, readers: PPDs are definetly not drivers, as they drive nothing; they only describe a printer’s capabilities, in order to enable the printing clients to adjust output, set configurations &c.  But they are the nearest thing one uses in modern systems that already have native Postscript and even perhaps PDF output, as drivers are not needed anymore.